# Extending WP's upload/insert media functionality

Tags: plugins, uploads

I am writing my first plugin to upload PDF files to a user specified directory other than the media directory specified in the Media menu under settings.

I need to extend the WP's native uploader so that files of a particular type in this case PDFs are uploaded to a different directory unlike images. In addition files uploaded in this user defined directory should be viewable in the native upload/insert window whenever the need arises to insert them into a page or a post.

Is it possible to extend WP's native uploader through a plugin or would I have to design my own uploader? This seems to be overkill for just one type of file considering that there is already an excellent uploader available.

I do not think that delving into WP's code and changing it is an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these are possible.

### Insert Attachment into Media Library

By using the [`wp_insert_attachment` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment), you can insert your uploaded images to the Media Library.

This is the example code from the Docs:

```
<?php
  $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
  $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $attachment = array(
     'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['baseurl'] . _wp_relative_upload_path( $filename ), 
     'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
     'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
     'post_content' => '',
     'post_status' => 'inherit'
  );
  $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, 37 );
  // you must first include the image.php file
  // for the function wp_generate_attachment_metadata() to work
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
  $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
?>
```

### Change Directory of Uploads

To change the directory of your uploads, you need to use the `upload_dir` filter. [Yoast has a pretty good tutorial](http://yoast.com/smarter-upload-handling-wp-plugins/) on how to do such.

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
$upload = wp_upload_dir();
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');

function my_upload_dir($upload) {
    $upload['subdir']   = '/sub-dir-to-use' . $upload['subdir'];
    $upload['path']     = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];
    $upload['url']      = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];
    return $upload;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this answer's my question I think the example code above would help me write the plugin. :-)